# what would be a better practice instead of chmod g+r /etc/shadow so I can use Unix user/group database for Jenkins authentication?

Tags: security, best-practices, jenkins

I don't want to run Jenkins as root, nor giving public access (or even group access) to /etc/shadow seems to a good idea.

as suggested by "Manage Jenkins" when selecting Linux user/group database:
"Either Jenkins needs to run as root or User 'httpd' needs to belong to group root and 'chmod g+r /etc/shadow' needs to be done to enable Jenkins to read /etc/shadow"

From a security stand point what would be the best practice while running Jenkins and still being able to perform some tasks as a super user (in case my jobs need that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better practice would be to [use the pwauth plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/pwauth), which lets you run jenkins as a non-root user, and only [pwauth itself](https://code.google.com/p/pwauth/) needs to be setuid root to perform the actual authentication.

Comment: Thanks! The only 2 things I needed to do besides installing the pwauth plugin was making sure I had the package for it installed on my ArchLinux server and making sure the paths under Advanced Path Configuration were correct.

Comment: Leaving this to help others:
`yaourt pwauth
usermod -a -G pwauth jenkins`